# Seleção de campos que se repetem no banco de dados MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados, com as colunas `id`, `assunto`, `mensagem`, `id_replicante`

Quero selecionar todos os registros desta tabela.

Porém, no campo `assunto` tem vários valores que se repetem, e eu gostaria que a minha seleção pegasse apenas 1 destes que se repetem.

Exemplo:

Na tabela:

```
(1, assunto1, mensagem1, 2)

(2, assunto1, mensagem2, 3)

(3, assunto2, mensagem3, 4)

(4, assunto3, mendagem4, 4)


SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE...
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

*assunto1,
assunto2,
assunto3,*

Comment: Independente de ser novato em PHP, seria bom se expressar melhor, pois dá pra entender de uma diversidade de maneiras sua pergunta. Dê uma lida em [ask], e procure ser mais claro. Você pode [edit] a resposta, e acrescentar mais detalhes para aumentar a chance de uma resposta que resolva seu problema.

Comment: Provavelmente com `GROUP BY` você resolve o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se é que eu entendi a pergunta:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela GROUP BY assunto
```

Troque o `assunto` pelo campo desejado. Depois você pode acrescentar os detalhes que precisa, como `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, etc, mas use a ordem certa:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ... GROUP BY assunto
```

Como mencionado pelo @fernando, lembre-se também do DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT(assunto) FROM tabela WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Podes adicionar um GROUP BY (para agrupar pelos assuntos).

SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE.... 
GROUP BY [coluna_assunto].

Digamos que a estrutura da tabela seja:
id, assunto, mensagem

Ficaria: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE ... GROUP BY assunto;

Comment: Além do group by podes também usar o DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT(assunto) FROM tabela;

Answer (score 1):

Acho que você pode usar o GROUP_BY do SQL pra isso. Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE (condição) GROUP_BY assunto;
```